# docker latest is not the newest

Tags: docker, version

How come docker latest image version is not the newest?

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY                    TAG         IMAGE ID       CREATED             SIZE
ghcr.io/puppeteer/puppeteer   19.11.1     9fcf6c4df310   2 days ago          2.02GB
ghcr.io/puppeteer/puppeteer   latest      41ce7a29b76d   3 days ago          2.02GB
```

Will I get older one when I run

`docker run -it ghcr.io/puppeteer/puppeteer /bin/sh` ?

As `docker inspect` also gives older.

```
docker inspect ghcr.io/puppeteer/puppeteer
[
    {
        "Id": "sha256:41ce7a29b76d0b6b7da3a477c47560f2653e850accc30c4c3d4a663dabbb8d4f",
```

Answer (score 0):

Having the latest image and having the `latest` TAG have two different things here Paul.

If I wish I can keep calling my older image with a `latest` tag, as it is just an alias from which docker understands the default version of the image.

If you wish to run a docker container with the latest image (like latest versionwise) you need to run it along with its tag.

i.e. `docker run -it ghcr.io/puppeteer/puppeteer:19.11.1 /bin/sh`

Hope this helps.